# usage of "come across"

Tags: word-usage

I guess I am aware the meaning of "come across"

> appear or sound in a specified way; give a specified impression.

This post focuses on the usage of "come across" with that meaning.

---

An [ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/196971/109190) uses "come across" this way

> You could say that without breaking grammar rules, but no one expresses that feeling in that way, and if they did, **it** would **come across fairly rude**.

There are **two** questions about that use.

First of all, the subject would usually be someone, e.g. a personal pronoun. "It" would probably be inappropriate. Is my understanding right?

Secondly, I see the examples on Cambridge Dictionary and Oxford Dictionary put "as" after the phrase

> After all, I appeared to be a bookworm sort of fellow trying to **come across as tough**.
>
> I didn't want to **come across as** patronizing, but I did.
>
> He **comes across as** a bit of a bore.

Is the word "as" required, optional or unnecessary there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all, the subject would usually be someone, human being. "it" would probably be inappropriate.

The subject isn't the person saying the phrase, the subject is the phrase itself.

There's no reason that the subject has to be a person. In fact, anything can be the subject.

*"That car comes across as a practical daily driver."*

> Is the word "as" required, optional or unnecessary there?

'As' is generally required. It looks like a typo in the original answer to me.

Comment: Do you agree that "the subject would usually be someone", according to the last three examples in my OP?

Comment: The subject *can* be someone, but it just as easily can be the phrase (or action, etc.) itself. I wouldn't say one is noticeably more common than the other.

Comment: So, you claim that something can be the subject when "come across" functions as a predicate, right?

Comment: Anything can be the subject. *"That car comes across as a practical daily driver."* There's no reason that it ever has to be limited to people.

Comment: Thank you, that's very kind of you. That's very good to know that. Would you please put that into your answer?